# Invalid attempt to read data when no data is present

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database in C# [built before I got to my present job, creator is gone], and it was fine until last week. On the first page `clerk_search.aspx` it searches SQL Server for people and posts back to a datagrid that's fine.

There is a ASP `Image` button that's clicked on and it goes forward to the next page, to enter the reason the for the customers visit with loaded fields about the customer that post back. For some persons the next page populates, for others it does not. The SQL statement used checks out fine in query analyzer, I don't understand. I don't think its the reader because others are logged in fine, and the other customers are present in the rows in SQL and can be queried just fine. All is posted below, I am not savvy with coding, please assist.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.
>
> SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
>   reader2.Read();
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.]

Here is the actual: ....`clerk_create.aspx.cs`

```
 public partial class clerk_create : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if (Request.Cookies["us"] == null)
         {
             Response.Write("Sorry, you do not have access to this page. Please see    
 data systems.");
             Response.End();
         }

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection    
 (WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["walkin2"].ConnectionString))
            {
                TextBox txtsct = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("Txtsct");
                Txtsct.Text = txtsct.Text; 
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("Txtssn");
                Txtssn.Text = "" + txt.Text;
                connection.Open();
                string strsql2 = "SELECT dbo.table_name.SSN,   
                dbo.table_name.LAST_NAME,      
                dbo.table_name.FIRST_NAME, dbo.table_name.MIDDLE_INITIAL, 
                dbo.table_name.COMPONENT_CODE, dbo.table_name.PRESENT_CODE FROM 
                dbo.table_name INNER JOIN dbo.table_name ON dbo.table_name.SSN = '" + 
                Txtssn.Text + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql2, connection);
                SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader2.Read();
                LblLName.Text = "" + reader2["LAST_NAME"];
                LblFName.Text = "" + reader2["FIRST_NAME"];
            }
        }
    }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Could be a number of things, but there is no `using` construct around the reader to make sure it's disposed correctly.

Comment: The `.Read()` method returns a bool - **true** if there was data read and can be accessed, **false** if there was no data (which can totally be the case when you're searching - right?). You need to check for that! `if (reader2.Read()) { ...... }`

Comment: There are all sorts of wrongness in this code.

Comment: i know the code is wrong, and was written by people who were percieved coders. I am a fresh Sys Admin with little coding backround and have been put in charge of the Web portals. Please help me try and make sense of this

Answer (score 3):

You should check the return value of  `Read` method.

If read method returns `false` then there is no more data. In that case you should not read the data from reader. Doing so will cause this exception.

If you're sure that you'll get only one record try this

```
if(reader2.Read())
{
    LblLName.Text = "" + reader2["LAST_NAME"];
    LblFName.Text = "" + reader2["FIRST_NAME"];
}
```

usually `DataReader` is used as below, since it can contain number of records

```
while (reader2.Read())
{
    //Consume reader using reader2["Column"] etc
}
```

Comment: Same invalid error Mr Sriram Invalid attempt...when no data is present, says error is line 42.....
Line 40:                SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
Line 41:                if (reader2.Read()) ;
Line 42:                LblLName.Text = "" + reader2["LAST_NAME"];
Line 43:                LblFName.Text = "" + reader2["FIRST_NAME"];
Line 44:                LblMI.Text = "" + reader2["MIDDLE_INITIAL"];

Comment: `reader2["MIDDLE_INITIAL"];` should also come inside if statement

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not properly disposing some objects and it is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

DTO:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
private static readonly Lazy<string> ConnectionString = new Lazy<string>(() => WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["walkin2"].ConnectionString);
private const string GetEmployeeBySSNQuery = "SELECT dbo.table_name.SSN, dbo.table_name.LAST_NAME, dbo.table_name.FIRST_NAME, dbo.table_name.MIDDLE_INITIAL, dbo.table_name.COMPONENT_CODE, dbo.table_name.PRESENT_CODE FROM dbo.table_name INNER JOIN dbo.table_name ON dbo.table_name.SSN = @SSN";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetEmployeeInformation();
    }
}

private void GetEmployeeInformation()
{
    var sctTextBox = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("Txtsct");
    Txtsct.Text = txtsct.Text; 
    var ssnTextBox = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("Txtssn");
    Txtssn.Text = ssnTextBox.Text;

    var ssn = ssnTextBox.Text;

    var employee = GetEmployeeBySSN(ConnectionString.Value, ssn);

    if(employee != null)
    {
        LblFName.Text = employee.FirstName;
        LblLName.Text = employee.LastName;
    }
}

private Employee GetEmployeeBySSN(string connectionString, string ssn)
{
    Employee employee = null;

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using(var command = new SqlCommand(GetEmployeeBySSNQuery, connection)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSN", ssn);

            using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if(reader.Read())
                {
                    employee = new Employee
                                {
                                    FirstName = Convert.ToString(reader["FIRST_NAME"]),
                                    LastName = Convert.ToString(reader["LAST_NAME"])
                                };
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return employee;
}
```

Comment: Good Afternoon Gentlemen, 

First, many thanks for all attempts at this, thank you for your thoughts, and lended 
expertise.The data base was written several years back, and continues to serve. The SQL 
injection is not an issue, if there is vulnerable point. Its very protected.

Im just wondering why.......

Comment: string strsql2 = "SELECT dbo.table_name.SSN,   
                dbo.table_name.LAST_NAME,      
                dbo.table_name.FIRST_NAME, dbo.table_name.MIDDLE_INITIAL, 
                dbo.table_name.COMPONENT_CODE, dbo.table_name.PRESENT_CODE FROM 
                dbo.table_name INNER JOIN dbo.table_name ON dbo.table_name.SSN = '" + 
                Txtssn.Text + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql2, connection);

Comment: It errors out on the below statement for last name when the data is clearly in the table, should i delete the table and rebuild? I don't think that would help, but i feel out of logical options        SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader2.Read();
                LblLName.Text = "" + reader2["LAST_NAME"];
                LblFName.Text = "" + reader2["FIRST_NAME"];

Comment: `reader2["LAST_NAME"]` is an object. Use the `Convert.ToString` method.